# Application in fixed landscape. How to detect phone orientation

Tags: android, screen, orientation, sensors

I'm building android app that is only in landscape mode. How can i detect the phone orientation as fast as possible? I have tried with

```
`Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

display.getOrientation();`
```

and also with the `SensorEventListener`, but I can't get any values for X,Y or Z? How can I do this? any solution? I was using this example for sensor.
[link for the sensor event listener](http://mobilestrategist.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-accelerometer-and-orientation.html)

Comment: onConfigurationChange does not work.

Comment: Can't you fix the orientation of the phone to landscape.

Comment: I need orientation of the phone and my app should stay in landscape mode all the time I need to register portrait or landscape?

Answer (score 0):

To keep an activity only in portrait mode add this in the manifest  xml tag

android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: my app is in landscape all the time, and I want to detect if the user has gone to portrait or landscape mode